# raspberry pi & gps python-mutithreading

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, python-multithreading

I am developing GPS(global sat bu-353s4 USB-type) and raspberry pi 3b based project. In which I want to fetch GPS latitude and longitude data, according to that data I want to play some video files and also want to keep track of last played video name. all this process should be in while loop means in an infinite loop.
I have developed logic for that, the problem I am facing is that whenever video playback is complete it will again fetch GPS data and go to specific folder select video file and play video, in between two video playback the screen gets blank I want continuous video play. I am using OMXplayer to open video.I know it can be solved using the multitasking /multithreading concept but don't know how to implement it in Python.
this is my code :

```
# class to define background process thread
class Asyncfun(threading.Thread):
def __init__(self, text):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.text = text

def run(self):
    os.system(self.text)
    print "play finished "
def Main(): 
try:
    while True:
        # get the GPS latitude longitude data using another gpsdatafetching file
        stdn = gps2.latlong()
        lat1 =  round(float(stdn[0]),5) 
        long1 = round(float(stdn[1]),5) 
        ID = gps_geotest3.test1(lat1,long1)# get the areaid according to current latitudeand longitude
        print "id is :", ID
        if ID == None:
            ID = 17
        print "lat long is in this areaId : ",ID
        location = '/home/pi/files/' 
        counter = 0 #keep a count of all files found
        mp4files = [] #list to store all csv files found at location
        lastplayedindex = 0
        areaID = str(ID)
        location += areaID
        #print "file path is: ",location
        for file in os.listdir(location):
            if file.endswith(".mp4"):
                #print "mp4 file found:\t", file
                mp4files.append(str(file))
                counter = counter+1

        #get the lastplayedindex_aeraid file name
        indexfilename='lastplayedindex_'        
        indexfilename +=areaID
        indexfilename += '.txt'
        #get the index number from lastplayedindex_aeraid file
        with open(indexfilename,'rb') as input_file:
            for line in input_file:
                lastplayedindex = line
        path = "/home/pi/files/" 
        omxcmd = "omxplayer --display=5 " 

        print "lastplayed index: ",lastplayedindex
        if int(lastplayedindex)< (counter-1) : #compare with total filecount in folder

            newlastindex=int(lastplayedindex)+1
            vfile = mp4files[newlastindex] #videofile name
            omxcmd += (location +'/') #append filelocation
            omxcmd += vfile # append filename
            #omxcmd is command to open videofile using OMXplayer
            #play videofile iin backgroundprocess while sending acknowledgment to webserver about that file
            background = Asyncfun(omxcmd)
            background.start()
            # code to update lastplayed index in local file

        counter = 0
        #to send acknowledgment to server about which video played last
        print "sending acknowledgment to server.."
        payload2 = {'DeviceMasterId': '30', 'Fk_Area_ID': areaID,'FileName':vfile}
        R = requests.post('url to my website', params = payload2)
        if R.status_code != 200:
            print "Error:", R.status_code
        else :
            print "acknowledgment sent successfully."
        background.join()
except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit): #when you press ctrl+c
    gpsp.running = False
    gpsp.join()
    scope.__del__()
if __name__ == '__main__':
Main()
```